# Python code works in local but "missing required positional arguments" on Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

**UPDATE :** Event the function is "✅" on Cloud Functions, even if you have an error when you click on "Deploy", the function can run with Cloud Scheduler, and works.

The following code imports data from Google Search Console to BigQuery. The code works locally and on Google Colab, and the datas are loaded on BigQuery.
But when I run the code on Cloud Functions there is a "missing 3 required positional arguments: 'start_date', 'end_date', and 'start_row" error.

I use the "get_sc_df" function as entry point.
If I change it and use the function "build" as entry point, I have also an error : "missing 3 required positional arguments: 'version' "
The code :

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

PROPERTIES = ["https://example.com"]
BQ_DATASET_NAME = 'my_dataset'
BQ_TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
CRED_PATH = "cred.json"
LOCATION = "europe-west1"
start_date = '2022-04-10'
end_date = '2022-04-14'
start_row = 0
version = 'v1'

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        CRED_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build(
    'searchconsole',
    'v1',
    credentials=credentials
)

def get_sc_df(site_url,start_date,end_date,start_row):
    """Grab Search Console data for the specific property and send it to BigQuery."""

    request = {
      'startDate': start_date,
      'endDate': end_date,
      'dimensions': ['query','device', 'page', 'date'], # uneditable to enforce a nice clean dataframe at the end!
      'rowLimit': 25000,
      'startRow': start_row
       }

    response = service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=site_url, body=request).execute()

    if len(response) > 1:

        x = response['rows']

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
        
        # split the keys list into columns
        df[['query','device', 'page', 'date']] = pd.DataFrame(df['keys'].values.tolist(), index= df.index)
        
        # Drop the key columns
        result = df.drop(['keys'],axis=1)

        # Add a website identifier
        result['website'] = site_url

        # establish a BigQuery client
        client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(CRED_PATH)
        dataset_id = BQ_DATASET_NAME
        table_name = BQ_TABLE_NAME
        # create a job config
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        # Set the destination table
        table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
        #job_config.destination = table_ref
        job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'

        load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(result, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
        load_job.result()

        return result
    else:
        print("There are no more results to return.")

# Loop through all defined properties, for up to 100,000 rows of data in each
for p in PROPERTIES:
    for x in range(0,100000,25000):
        y = get_sc_df(p, '2022-04-10', '2022-04-10', x)
        if len(y) < 25000:
            break
        else:
            continue
```

What can I fix to make the code runs on Google Cloud Functions ?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You should check the structure of Cloud Functions syntax. What is the cf entry point. What is the cf payload.

Answer (score 0):

From the part -- def get_sc_df(site_url,start_date,end_date,start_row):
remove start_row and only keep as below
def get_sc_df(site_url,start_date,end_date):

or you can try below as well.

def get_sc_df(start_date,end_date,start_row):